# Is that possible to Emacs to respect .gitattributes and .hgeol?

Tags: git, mercurial

Is that possible to Emacs to respect `.gitattributes` and `.hgeol`?

I am again on Windows with Cygwin `emacs-w32` and would like if Emacs honor project specific CR/LF settings for new files...

Comment: I can't tell whether you're already familiar with [directory-local variables](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables) in Emacs. If adding a `.dir-locals.el` file to the project is acceptable, you can always use that. It's not what you're asking for, but it might still be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Not directly an answer to your question, but I would try out editorconfig:

https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-emacs#readme

This will allow you to add a config file which will set line endings, line length, indent style, and more and have it respected by every editor with a plugin.